Go from $=1 = \frac{25}{16} \cos^2 \theta$ to $\cos^2 \theta = \frac{16}{25}$

Determine without a calculator cos v since tan v=-34 and v is an angle in the fourth quadrant.

$\tan \theta = \frac{\sin \theta}{\cos \theta} = -\frac{3}{4}$
Attempt:
$\frac{\sin \theta}{\cos \theta} = -\frac{3}{4}$
$\frac{\sin^2 \theta}{\cos^2 \theta} = (-\frac{3}{4})^2$
$\frac{\sin^2 \theta}{\cos^2 \theta} = \frac{9}{16}$
$\frac{1 - \cos^2 \theta}{\cos^2 \theta} = \frac{9}{16}$
$\cos^2 \theta \frac{1 - \cos^2 \theta}{\cos^2 \theta} = \frac{9}{16} \cos^2 \theta$
$1 = \frac{9}{16} \cos^2 \theta + \frac{16}{16} \cos^2 \theta$
$1 = \frac{25}{16} \cos^2 \theta$
I am supposed to get to: $\cos^2 \theta = \frac{16}{25}$ not sure, how I am supposed to go to this part.
The final answer is supposed to be: $cos v = \frac{4}{5}$.

A word of advice - don't start each line with an equals sign if you're just bringing things down. It makes it very, very hard to read.

You already have $1 = \frac{25}{16} \cdot  \cos^2 \theta$, and you are asking how to get $\cos^2 \theta = \frac{16}{25}$ ? – If $1 = \frac{25}{16} \cdot  X$ then what is $X$?

$\tan v = -34$, as given by the quote. But where does $\tan \theta = -\frac 34$ come from, and how does $\theta$ relate to $v$?

@peterwhy Perhaps it was copied and pasted and not checked.

Instead of relying on identities, it's much easier to draw the triangle.
Since $\theta$ lies in the fourth quadrant and you know the $\tan \theta = -\frac{3}{4}$, you know that we can consider the point $(4, -3).$ Draw that point and complete the right triangle with one leg perpendicular to the $x$-axis.
Use Pythagoras and...

 The hypotenuse has length 5 and thus $\cos \theta = \frac{4}{5}.$

For your intended work - if your last line of work is $$1 = \frac{25}{16} \cos^2 \theta$$ then simply multiply both sides by $\frac{16}{25}$ and take square roots. Remember - isolate the thing you're trying to solve for, and think in terms of simple inverse operations, as in elementary algebra.
I personally perfer the first method with a picture (not attached).

Sean, thanks. How do you get 16/25 when I have 25/16. this is the confusing part for me. Shouldn't it be multiply by 25/16 on both sides?

Try that and see what happens - is $\frac{25}{16} \cdot \frac{25}{16} =1?$

Sean, on a calculator = 2.44140625, so, I suppose thaat's wrong.
